# Apply body tag to separate components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do I apply different body tags to different components, i.e. if I want to apply body to a dashboard component but also want a different body for the sign up page component?

Comment: What does this have to do with AngularJS?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. There is only one `body` element (and thus only one pair of body tags [`<body>` and `</body>`]) in a document. What do you mean by "apply"ing a different "body tag"?

Comment: Is it possible to apply different classes to different body tags for components - i.e My dashboard component, I want it to have <body className="dashboard"> and perhaps the home component can have <body className="home-page" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[React Body ClassName module](https://github.com/iest/react-body-classname) does exactly what you say.

In your Dashboard component just render somewhere `<BodyClassName className="dashboard" />` and do the same for Home component, eg. `<BodyClassName className="home-page" />`.

You can also wrap components between `<BodyClassName className="xyz">...</BodyClassName>` tags and do other things like render them conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> Is it possible to apply different classes to different body tags for components - i.e My dashboard component, I want it to have  and perhaps the home component can have

No, not within React itself,a component can't reach out and modify its container.

Stepping outside React, you can always put DOM manipulation code in a component. For instance, you could set the class in `componentDidMount` and remove it in `componentWillUnmount`.

Example (this uses `classList`, be sure to check your target browsers, you may have to work with `className` instead):

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {flag: true};
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
  toggle() {
    const flag = !this.state.flag;
    console.log(flag);
    this.setState({flag});
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.toggle);
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="button" value="Toggle" onClick={this.toggle} />
        {this.state.flag ? <Foo /> : <Bar />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add("foo");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove("foo");
  }
  render() {
    return <div>This is foo</div>;
  }
}

class Bar extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.classList.add("bar");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.classList.remove("bar");
  }
  render() {
    return <div>This is bar</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
.bar {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```